# Pandas index match without merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

So I have two dataframes. activity_log records when a client logs in based on their client_id. A client_id can appear multiple times given the client logs in multiple times over a period.

I need to create a third column in this activity_log looks up the date that the client was created. This created_date is calculated by looking at the earliest user_created date in the user_table.

activity_log

| client_id | activity_date | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/12/2022 |  |
| 1 | 11/12/2022 |  |
| 1 | 9/12/2022 |  |
| 1 | 8/12/2022 |  |
| 2 | 12/12/2022 |  |
| 2 | 11/12/2022 |  |
| 3 | 10/12/2022 |  |
| 3 | 9/12/2022 |  |

user_table

| client_id | user_id | user_created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12asdasd3 | 12/12/2021 |
| 1 | 1sads23 | 11/12/2021 |
| 1 | asasdsa2 | 10/12/2021 |
| 2 | 32asdasd1 | 12/12/2021 |
| 2 | 3asdasd21 | 11/12/2021 |
| 3 | 1asdsaa22 | 2/12/2021 |

I have tried using pandas merge

```
activity_log.merge(client_table[['client_id','user_created']], how='inner', on='client_id')
```

The problem with this is that I end up with a table that is grater in size than the original activity_log because the client_id appears multiple times in the activity_log and multiple times in the user_table.

I want to look up the client_id in the user_table, get the earliest user_created value and put that into the created_date column in the activity_log.

Any ideas on what else I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to take the earliest event from `usr_df`, you can do that with `groupby` and `first` after sorting by date:

```
df1 = usr_df.sort_values('user_created', ascending = True).groupby('client_id').first()
```

`df1` looks like this:

```
     user_id    user_created
client_id       
1   asasdsa2    2021-10-12
2   3asdasd21   2021-11-12
3   1asdsaa22   2021-02-12
```

now you can merge act_df with this one:

```
act_df.merge(df1, on = 'client_id')
```

output:

```
      client_id  activity_date    user_id    user_created
--  -----------  ---------------  ---------  -------------------
 0            1  12/12/2022       asasdsa2   2021-10-12 00:00:00
 1            1  11/12/2022       asasdsa2   2021-10-12 00:00:00
 2            1  9/12/2022        asasdsa2   2021-10-12 00:00:00
 3            1  8/12/2022        asasdsa2   2021-10-12 00:00:00
 4            2  12/12/2022       3asdasd21  2021-11-12 00:00:00
 5            2  11/12/2022       3asdasd21  2021-11-12 00:00:00
 6            3  10/12/2022       1asdsaa22  2021-02-12 00:00:00
 7            3  9/12/2022        1asdsaa22  2021-02-12 00:00:00
```